# How to send a structure across multiple processes using MPI_Allreduce()?

Tags: c++, struct, mpi, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I am very new to MPI Programming and I am stuck at a part of my coding. I have local count min sketches across all the processes where they are being initialized and updated parallelly independently i.e. I am generating local count min sketches with local hashes in individual processes.
Now I want to do a MPI_Allreduce() so that all the processes have the global view of these sketches. I am not understanding how I should initialize the size of this global sketch and how I will send all the members of the structures. Do I need to do MPI_Allreduce() for all the members of the structure separately?

Structure of the count min sketch is

```
 struct CM_type{
     long long count;
     int depth;
     int width;
     int ** counts;
     unsigned int *hasha, *hashb;
 } CM_type;
```

and the initialization and update is like this

```
#pragma omp parallel shared (width, depth, prng, all_kmers)
{
   #pragma omp for
      for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) //size is the number of processes
      {
          CM_type cm_loc;
          
          cm_loc.depth=depth;
          cm_loc.width=width;
          cm_loc.count=0;
          cm_loc.counts=(int **)calloc(sizeof(int *),cm_loc.width);
          cm_loc.counts[0]=(int *)calloc(sizeof(int), cm_loc.depth*cm_loc.width);
          
          cm_loc.hasha=(unsigned int *)calloc(sizeof(unsigned int),cm_loc.depth);
          cm_loc.hashb=(unsigned int *)calloc(sizeof(unsigned int),cm_loc.depth);
          if (cm_loc.counts && cm_loc.hasha && cm_loc.hashb && cm_loc.counts[0])
            {
                for (j=0;j<depth;j++)
                {
                    
                      cm_loc.hasha[j]=prng_int(prng) & MOD;
                        cm_loc.hashb[j]=prng_int(prng) & MOD;
                      // pick the hash functions
                        cm_loc.counts[j]=(int *) cm_loc.counts[0]+(j*cm_loc.width);
                      
                }
            }
            //Update function
      }
 }
```

I am happy to provide any more information if needed and thank you for all the help.

Comment: You can send a single `CM_type` in one shot by using an ad hoc derived datatype (with `MPI_Type_create_struct()`) and then use `MPI_BOTTOM`. Note you also have to use `MPI_IN_PLACE` (e.g. send buffer == recv buffer).

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet would you like to provide an answer ?

Comment: @dreamcrash no, but feel free to post an elaborated answer.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thank you I will look into those. I have never used MPI_BOTTOM or MPI_IN_PLACE so will see how to use those.